# VoiceOver reads Label even when button is double-tapped

Tags: ios, audio, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have set up the customized Hint for my UIButton. What I expect is that when single-tapped, the button will read the Hint; when double-tapped the Hint will *not* sound, but the normal button action will happen.

But in fact, the Hint is read again on double-tap, while at the same time the normal button action happens. The re-reading would be annoying enough, but the normal action is to play a different sound. They wind up being combined. Yecch!

One would think the UIAccessibilityTraitPlaysSound would be the thing to use, but it has no effect. I could just use AllowsDirectInteraction, but would then lose the Hint. In any case, the re-reading of the Hint on double-tap is just wrong. IMHO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the plays sound trait refers to the activation sound (that sounds like a brief "blip"), and is used for an element that wants to play its own activation sound.

If you are playing anything more/longer than an activation sound, I think that you should be using the starts media session trait instead.

> ```
> UIAccessibilityTraitStartsMediaSession
> ```
>
> The accessibility element starts a media session when it is activated.
>
> You can use this trait to silence the audio output of an assistive technology, such as VoiceOver, during a media session that should not be interrupted. For example, you might use this trait to silence VoiceOver speech while the user is recording audio.

Comment: That's it. The docs are pretty scanty on this. But I should know that means to just try everything. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! But what if I want to call UIAccessibility.post(notification: .announcement ...) on button tap? (I need to declare if the answer was correct or no without repeating it again)